# Modify Javascript / node object properties as list

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I'm working in a serveless + lambda + dynamodb environment and I can't get a clue for this.

I've a function like:

```
getList : () =>  {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var params = {param1 : value1, param2: value2} //parameters for a DB query
        getItemsfromDB(params, function(err, data) { //get all items in a table, returns a Promise
            if (err) return reject(err); 
            data.Items.forEach ((item, index) : => { //Items constain a obejct, with list of objects, like a arraym return another Promise.
                getItemPropDetailsfromDB(item.prop1, (itemDetails) : => { //I get item by item details from another table. item.prop1 is string
                    data.Items[index].prop1 =  itemDetails; //replace string with object details
                    //log says that at this time, itemDetails are the object retrived as I want. 

                });
            })
            return resolve(data.Items) // return the initial prop1 string
    }
}
```

I don't know how to modify the original object, or return an new object. I make a LOT of test, but I can't figure out where I'm wrong 
Sorry for my english and my (maybe) incomplete information, I don't know what more to test.

**UPDATE**
finally i solved this :

```
getList : () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
var params = {param1 : value1, param2: value2} //parameters for a DB query
getItemsfromDB(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) return reject(err);
    Promise.all(data.Items.map((item, index) => new Promise((resolve) =>
        getItemPropDetailsfromDB(item.prop1, (itemDetails) => {
        var newItem = data.Items[index];//map() return a new object with modifies properties, so i copy one by one
        newItem.prop1 = itemDetails;//replace prop1 

        return resolve(newItem);//return modified item
        })//this return a new object.
    ))).then((newData) => => {return resolve(newData)}) //then i retrive the new object
  })
})
```

thanks for help !

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do seems strange and should probably be done some other way, but try this:

```
getList : () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  var params = {param1 : value1, param2: value2} //parameters for a DB query
  getItemsfromDB(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) return reject(err);
    Promise.all(data.Items.map((item, index) => new Promise((resolve) =>
      getItemPropDetailsfromDB(item.prop1, (itemDetails) => {
        data.Items[index].prop1 = itemDetails;
        resolve(itemDetails);
      })
    ))).then(() => resolve(data.Items))
  })
})
```

Also note `getItemPropDetailsfromDB` doesn't seem to invoke its callback with the typical error-first approach so I have no idea what will happen if that function runs into an error (will it invoke its callback with `undefined` or will it simply not invoke the callback at all?).

Comment: Thanks ! Actually, i don't did an exception handler because I'm stuck there, anyway, I tried your sugestion and i get the same object when i log data.item before the last resolve. Is a great starting point, I'm new in Promises objects.

Comment: @Lucas so if you do `getList().then((items) => console.log(items))` it doesn't eventually output the modified items?